# Does Dropbox encrypt the files locally before uploading?

Tags: sync, dropbox

Are the files encrypted before they're uploaded or are the files encrypted on the server after being uploaded? If the former, is it a block cipher that is used locally? Is the key available to the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropbox uses data deduplication. For this to work efficiently, everything needs to be encrypted with the same key. Otherwise, even if multiple people had the same file, it would have a different ciphertext for everyone, making deduplication impossible.

This key is of course known only to Dropbox. Still, Dropbox could, theoretically, read all your data. Also, hackers might obtain the key, although proper security should make this very hard.

Data blocks are protected in transport by TLS with AES encryption.

Comment: But deduplication could be achieved with either local or remote encryption, right? For instance, 1. encrypt locally 2. match local encrypted blocks against remote encrypted blocks 3. upload diff.

Comment: @Kate Deduplication at Dropbox works ([well, used to, anyway](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54633/does-dropbox-no-longer-de-duplicate-files-across-users)) on a global level. Otherwise, it just isn’t worth it. This is also how the Photo Upload “hack” worked: Because everyone used the same file, only one person had to actually upload the file.

Comment: Sorry, does that mean files are encrypted remotely only?

Comment: Most likely. Dropbox definitely has the key, anyway: [“Not all mobile media players support encrypted streaming, so media files streamed from our servers aren't always encrypted.”](https://www.dropbox.com/security#protection)